# Meaning of "nip past" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "nip" mean in football (soccer) context?

SHOT! Mata **nip** past Ferdinand to open up space for a shot but it's on his right and he hits it straight at De Gea

Comment: _Nip_, at least in British English,  is a common colloquialism for 'go quickly'. "I'm just going to nip to the shop for some more bread."

Comment: It should be "Mata **nips** past Ferdinand". I nip. You nip. He nips.